# Is there a limitation in quantity of joined tables using spatialite views?

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite, spatial-view

I've one point layer in qgis and several non spatial tables in a spatialite database. Now I want to create a view as you can see in the following:

`CREATE VIEW testansicht10

AS SELECT baumkataster.baum_ID AS ROWID,

baumkataster.geom AS geom,

gattung.gattung AS gattung,

art.art AS art,

sorte.sorte AS sorte,

baumkataster.b_hoehe AS b_hoehe,

baumkataster.kro_durchm AS kro_durchm,

baumkataster.kro_ansatz AS kro_ansatz,

baumkataster.age AS age

FROM baumkataster JOIN gattung ON baumkataster.gattung = gattung.gattung_ID

JOIN art ON baumkataster.art = art.art_ID

JOIN sorte ON baumkataster.sorte=sorte.sorte_ID;`

When I do this the result is an empty view table though there are entries in my spatial table. If I exclude one of my joined tables (for instance "sorte") in the view I get the desired result - the view table with the existing entries. Is there a limitation in quantity of joined tables? The view should consist of about 65 coulomns (36 are from joined tables).

Comment: The maximum number of tables in a join is 64, according to http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Its easy to make a mistake with this sort of construct, and it almost always helps to break it down into pieces. Instead of trying to create a VIEW, just do the SELECT first. Instead of doing all the JOINs in one hit, just do one at a time. Try removing the art.art AS art and sorte.sorte AS sorte which might be a problem in the JOINs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could fix the problem! As BradHards recommended I did it step by step. I also found out that there was a conflict with allowing NULL-values in one table but not in the other. Thats why I get a result when all fields are filled but not when one field has NULL-value.